# (Resolvido) Firebase Google só conecta em apps pelo 4G, pelo wifi não

Tags: android, firebase, google

Estou desenvolvendo um app que usa o Firebase.
Tive muito problemas W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
Julgando ser esse o caso investi muito tempo tentando resolver isso.

Percebi que ele até conecta se ficar a tela de login uns 30 segundos ele acaba logando no firebase. Muito lento.

Quando fiz um teste pelo 4G e funcionou muito bem  e muito rápido. Eu peguei outro aplicativo qualquer do meu telefone como no caso Glotify que deve usar serviços do google, pra minha surpresa também ficou lento e não conectou.

De novo tirei do wifi , tentei de novo nesse app em questão e funcionou muito rápido varias vezes. Não é o meu wifi a que de casa não pois fui em outro lugar e tambem não funcionou.
Bom era a mesma operadora de internet A NET.

Eu até vou por o codigo aqui, mas como funciona pelo 4G, e tudo certinho. E o outro aplicativo de uma grande empresa (glorify) também não funciona no login.

Vem a pergunta: É no google, ou na operadora?

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_login );
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.getUid ();
    try {
        if ( mAuth != null ) {
           String  uid = mAuth.getUid ();
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace ( );
    }

    // Configure Google Sign In
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder( GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    editEmail = findViewById( R.id.email );
    editSenha = findViewById( R.id.password );
    btnCancelarLogin = findViewById (R.id.btnCancelarLogin );
    btnCancelarLogin.setOnClickListener (this);
    btnGoogleConection = findViewById (R.id.btnGoogleConection );
    btnGoogleConection.setOnClickListener (this);
    btnForgotPassword = findViewById (R.id.btnEsqueci_Senha );
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog( this );

    // Create token receiver (for demo purposes only)
    mTokenReceiver = new TokenBroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onNewToken(String token) {
            Log.d( TAG, "onNewToken:" + token );
            setCustomToken( token );
        }
    };

}

private void logarUsuario(){
    final String email = editEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String senha = editSenha.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        progressDialog.setMessage( getString( R.string.iniciando_login) );
        progressDialog.show();

        //Consultar se leader existe
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, senha )
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener <AuthResult> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checando sucesso
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            int pos = email.indexOf("@");
                            String user = email.substring(0,pos);
                            Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, getString( R.string.logado_sucesso),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(currentUser);
                            editEmail.getEditText().setText("");
                            editSenha.getEditText().setText("");
                            Intent home = new Intent( LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class );
                            startActivity( home );
                          //  startSignIn();
                        }else{  //se houver colisão de mesmo usuário
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                                Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, getString( R.string.usuario_existe),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                HomeActivity.Logado = false;
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this,getString( R.string.falha_login), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                HomeActivity.Logado = false;
                            }

                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                } );

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace ( );
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId ( );
    if ( id == R.id.btnEnviarLogin ) {
        logarUsuario ( );
    } else if ( id == R.id.btnCancelarLogin ) {
        finishAffinity ( );
    }else if ( id == R.id.btnEsqueci_Senha){
        Intent remember = new Intent( LoginActivity.this, RememberActivity.class );
        startActivity( remember );
    }else if (id == R.id.btnRegistro){
        Intent register= new Intent( LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class );
        startActivity( register );
    }else if(id == R.id.btnGoogleConection){
        signIn();
    }
}

    public static void updateUI(FirebaseUser user){
    if (user != null) {
        HomeActivity.Logado = true;
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

        // Check if user's email is verified
        boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();

        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
        // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
        // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
        String uid = user.getUid();

    } else {
        HomeActivity.Logado = false;
    }
}

//start google conection
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    progressDialog.setMessage( getString( R.string.iniciando_login) );
    progressDialog.show();
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                    Intent home = new Intent( LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class );
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity( home );

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    updateUI(null);
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
}
//finish google connection

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: É um problema pessoal que não sei como resolver. Alguém sabe sobre isso?

Comment: Pelas negativas que to recebendo; acredito que eu deva dizer pro meu cliente usar o app só no 4G então. Se um moderador tiver a gentilesa de me dizer o que há de errado na minha pergunta agradeceria.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bom indo no stackoverflow em inglês no post [Couldn't connect to firebase database via WIFI but connects fine with 4G mobile network. Strange issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609349/couldnt-connect-to-firebase-database-via-wifi-but-connects-fine-with-4g-mobile) eu vi em uma resposta

> The solution for me was to replace the internet service provider SIM card as I'm using 4G access point in my home.

Então fiquei pensando no meu caso, e fui em outra rede, conectei no wifi e funcionou. Então percebi que poderia ser algo no meu modem. Reinicei meu modem e meu app voltou a connectar no Firebase no meu wifi.

No outro lugar que também não funcionou acredito que deva ser reiniciado o modem de lá também.(obs. lembrei que a net deles as vezes trava).

Não sei o porque desse erro no modem, mas pra mim isso resolveu.

**Reiniciar o Modem** funcinou!

Para aqueles que negativaram a minha pergunta um abraço.

Answer (score -3):

Primeiramente , não há nada de errado com a sua pergunta. Eu me deparei com o mesmo problema que você usando o Firebase Realtime Database e o FirebaseAuth . No meu caso ele não funcionava com a rede 4g , com a wi-fi sim , e quando usado com a 4g e um VPN, também. Na minha opinião , se trata de um problema do próprio Firebase com a configuração de alguns tipos de roteadores , o que explicaria esse comportamento. Ao usar um VPN , a conexão passa por outros servidores , utilizando outros roteadores , e ocorre naturalmente. Basicamente , não há nada que se possa fazer no código da aplicação para contornar esse tipo de comportamento no Firebase.